# How to calculate monthly average from daily files in R?

Tags: r

I have [365 binary files][1]. I want to calculate the monthly average. So from the *365 files*,

This code will take the average of every 30 files.

```
results <- list()
for (.files in files.group) {
      x <- do.call(rbind,(lapply(.files, readBin  , double() , size = 4, n =360 * 720, 
                 signed =T)))
          results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- colMeans(x)
    }
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas on:

Comment: You have too many questions in this question. For example, one of the questions is "For a given year, how do I get the number of days in each month?" which you could compute with some of the date functions, or just code in the usual lengths of the months and test for leap years (but you have 365 files, so its not a leap year?). Then there's the question of your no-data value, and various other problems with loops which you seem to have worked out already. Break the problem down, ask one question per post here.

Comment: @Wafa: PLEASE don't just remove and re-post a question. I had already posted a few code snippets in the comments of your original question that might have made it easier for me and others to answer your question. These are now lost. You made life harder for everyone around. Next time, please just edit your question if you have something new to add or need to clarify (not getting answers is a good indicator for this). I was going to take a swing at this today, but frankly, I don't fancy having to re-think stuff I already thought about.

Comment: Stephan Kolassa,I am terribly sorry.In fact,I was trying to modify the question but it was deleted by mistake.and I could not retrieve it.

Comment: You can change special values in a vector foo to NA with foo[foo==-32765] <- NA. Do this before calculating means, then use na.rm=TRUE in colMeans or mean. As to your other questions, it would help if your 365 files were named by date - are they? – Stephan Kolassa 17 hours ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dir1 <- "C:\\New folder (4)\\New folder"
files <- list.files(dir1, "*.bin",full.names=TRUE)
```

First you have to extract the number of the file (because they are not sorted the way you want them to be sorted (i. e. "ET10.bin" comes after "ET1.bin" and not "ET9.bin").

```
step1 <- strsplit(gsub("\\.bin","",files),split="ET")
filenumber <- do.call(rbind,step1)[,2]
```

Then this number is the day of the year in numerical form (recognized by `strptime` as `%j`). Let's say the year in question is 2012:

```
step2 <- strptime(paste(filenumber,"2012",sep="-"),format="%j-%Y")
files.group <- split(files, cut(step2, "month"))
```

Concerning the -999 values something like `x[x == -999] <- NA` should do the trick as long as you remember excluding the NA values when computing your average values (i. e. `colMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE)`)

**Edit**: As per @f3lix suggestion you can obtain `filenumber` in a more straightforward way:

```
dir1 <- "C:\\New folder (4)\\New folder"
files <- list.files(dir1, "*.bin",full.names=TRUE)
filenumber <- gsub(".*ET([0-9]+).bin", "\\1", files)
files.group <- split(files, cut(strptime(paste(filenumber,"2012",sep="-"),format="%j-%Y"), "month"))
```

Then your loop:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:12) {
    x <- do.call(rbind,(lapply(files.group[[i]], readBin  , 
                               double() , size = 4, n =360 * 720, signed =T)))
    x[x == -999] <- NA
    results[[i]] <- colMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    }

for (i in seq_along(results)) {
    fileName <- sprintf("C:\\Users\\New folder\\glo_%d.flt", i)
    writeBin(as.double(results[[i]]), fileName, size = 4)
    }
```

Comment: I modified the code to correct it (and actually simplify it). I did test it before but being on a Mac the separator for the directories are "/" and not "\\", so I modified my code when posting, but made a mistake doing so.

Comment: How about `step3=strptime(paste(gsub("ET([0-9]+).bin", "\\1", files),"2012"), format="%j %Y")` ...

Comment: @f3lix that's nice, except the elements of `files` are of the form "C:\\New folder (4)\\New folder\\ET1.bin" and not just "ET1.bin".

Comment: But that would indeed be a more straightforward way to go. Anyhow, here I broke down the code in several lines so that the meaning become obvious, otherwise the entire code can obviously be written in one single statement: `split(files, cut(strptime(paste(do.call(rbind,strsplit(gsub("\\.bin","",files),split="ET"))[,2],"2012",sep="-"),format="%j-%Y"), "month"))`

Comment: @plannapus: just add `.*` to my regexp like this `gsub(".*ET([0-9]+).bin", "\\1", files)`. This should also remove the whole path in front of the 'ET'...

Comment: @f3lix thanks that 's definitely better and less prone to the kind of mistake I did previously. I added it to my answer.

Comment: the code as you wrote it in your edit works perfectly well for me. You probably made a typo causing the second loop to be nested in your first loop.

Comment: Oh and of course if you re running the code several times in a row, remember to reinitialize `results<-list()` each time otherwise your loop will add to it. Another way to counter that would have been to have written your loop the following way instead of the way you did: `for (i in 1:12){x<-do.call(rbind,(lapply(files.group[[i]], ...`and then `results[[i]] <- colMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE)}`. I'll add everything to my answer in case I'm not clear enough here.