# Get monthly means from dataframe of several years of daily temps

Tags: r

I have daily temperature values for several years, 1949-2010. I would like to calculate monthly means. Here is an example of the data:

```
head(tmeasmax)
TIMESTEP   MEAN.C. MINIMUM.C. MAXIMUM.C. VARIANCE.C.2. STD_DEV.C.      SUM COUNT
1949-01-01  6.836547       6.65       7.33    0.02850574  0.1688364 1.426652     6
1949-01-02 10.533371      10.24      10.74    0.06140426  0.2477988 1.426652     6
1949-01-03 18.746729      18.02      19.78    0.18507860  0.4302076 1.426652     6
1949-01-04 21.244562      20.09      22.40    0.76106980  0.8723931 1.426652     6
1949-01-05  3.826716       3.11       5.37    0.52706647  0.7259935 1.426652     6
1949-01-06  9.127782       8.46      10.26    0.20236358  0.4498484 1.426652     6

str(tmeasmax)
'data.frame':   22645 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ TIMESTEP     : Date, format: "1949-01-01" "1949-01-02" ...
 $ MEAN.C.      : num  6.84 10.53 18.75 21.24 3.83 ...
 $ MINIMUM.C.   : num  6.65 10.24 18.02 20.09 3.11 ...
 $ MAXIMUM.C.   : num  7.33 10.74 19.78 22.4 5.37 ...
 $ VARIANCE.C.2.: num  0.0285 0.0614 0.1851 0.7611 0.5271 ...
 $ STD_DEV.C.   : num  0.169 0.248 0.43 0.872 0.726 ...
 $ SUM          : num  1.43 1.43 1.43 1.43 1.43 ...
 $ COUNT        : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```

[There is a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394812/how-to-calculate-monthly-average-from-daily-files-in-r) that I couldn't make heads or tails of. I imagine I can probably use `aggregate`, but I don't know how to break up the dates into the years and months and then approach the nesting of the months inside the years. I tried a loop inside of a loop, but I can never get nested loops to work.

EDIT to reply to comments/questions:
I was looking for the mean of "MEAN.C."

Comment: Monthly means of which column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick `data.table` solution. I assuming you want the means of `MEAN.C.` (?)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tmeasmax)[, .(MontlyMeans = mean(MEAN.C.)), by = .(year(TIMESTEP), month(TIMESTEP))]
#    year month MontlyMeans
# 1: 1949     1    11.71928
```

You can also do this for all the columns at once if you want

```
tmeasmax[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(year(TIMESTEP), month(TIMESTEP))]
#    year month  MEAN.C. MINIMUM.C. MAXIMUM.C. VARIANCE.C.2. STD_DEV.C.      SUM COUNT
# 1: 1949     1 11.71928     11.095   12.64667     0.2942481   0.482513 1.426652     6
```

Comment: David, in your second example, should `tmeasmax` be `setDT(tmeasmax)`?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Still getting the hang of `data.table`.

Comment: @eipi10 `setDT` updates by reference. Once you ran it once, your data set will become a `data.table` from now on.

Comment: @David Arenburg, thank you. Do the periods, for example " ... `by = .(year(TIMESTEP) ` " have certain significance? Are they something particular to specific functions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You will use `by` to specify aggregators. `year` and `month` are built in functions in the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tmeasmax$TIMESTEP = ymd(tmeasmax$TIMESTEP)

tmeasmax %>% 
  group_by(Year=year(TIMESTEP), Month=month(TIMESTEP)) %>%
  summarise(meanDailyMin=mean(MINIMUM.C.),
            meanDailyMean=mean(MEAN.C.))

  Year Month meanDailyMin meanDailyMean
1 1949     1       11.095      11.71928
```

You can summarise any other column by month in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lubridate` package to create a new factor variable consisting of the year-month combinations, then use `aggregate`.

```
library('lubridate')

tmeasmax2 <- within(tmeasmax, {
        monthlies <- paste(year(TIMESTEP),
                           month(TIMESTEP))
})

aggregate(tmeasmax2, list(monthlies), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```